# SimpleMembership Provider not assigning ID's

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm trying to get an MVC4 site with SQL working using SimpleMembership, but I keep getting errors whenever I create a user record:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'NFBC.dbo.User'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1753346
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5295154
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +242
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1682
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +269
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +1325
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +175
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +205
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +160
   WebMatrix.Data.Database.Execute(String commandText, Object[] args) +116
   WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseWrapper.Execute(String commandText, Object[] parameters) +55
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateUserRow(IDatabase db, String userName, IDictionary`2 values) +1074
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateUserAndAccount(String userName, String password, Boolean requireConfirmation, IDictionary`2 values) +102
   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(String userName, String password, Object propertyValues, Boolean requireConfirmationToken) +127
   NFBC.Controllers.AccountController.Register(RegisterModel model) in e:\PROJECTS\DEVELOPMENT\00-Current\NFBC\NFBC\Controllers\AccountController.cs:74
```

So to me this says that it's trying to insert a row into my user table but it's not setting the "Id" property, which is the primary key of the table. This ID is an int column as required by the provider. Here's how the code is running:

```
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("NFBCEntitiesRaw", "User", "Id", "Email1", autoCreateTables: true);
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

Id is an int primary key column, Email1 is the username column, nvarchar(255).

And the Connection string to the database:

```
<add name="NFBCEntitiesRaw" connectionString="data source=localhost;initial catalog=NFBC;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I've examined the source code for WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount, SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateUserAndAccount, and SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateUserRow, and at no point in any of those methods does the source code assign an ID to the User record, which would confirm why an exception is being thrown. But the method doesn't allow me to specify the ID, and when this sample was running against SQLExpress, it seemed to assign the ID just fine... so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks!

Comment: It did just occur to me that maybe I'm supposed to set the database up to auto-assign that column with incrementing values, but I can't find anywhere in the docs that specify to do that... is that the solution?

Comment: Is this connecting to a SQL Server instance?

Comment: Yes, full SQL server instance. I figured out I needed to use the Identity feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are connecting to a full-fledged MS SQL database (like SQL Server 2008), you need to mark the primary key field as an **identity** field if you want auto-increment. You'll need to open your table in design mode (assuming you are using *Server Management Studio* or *Visual Studio*, right-click the table and click 'Design'). Select the `ID` column, and then scroll the `Column Properties` pane until you can see the `Identity Specification` property. Change `IsIdentity` to `true`, save, and you're done. It should look like this:

[image]

HTH.

Comment: Yes that did the trick. I kind of suspected I needed to do this after I submitted the question, but it just seems odd that this would be required by the SimpleMembership system without mentioning it. Oh well. I'd upvote this answer but apparently I don't have enough reputation yet. Thanks!